# Mount/dismount database for migration

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, content-database, database

I'm mirgrating from one domain to another. 
Finally managed to get the new sharepoint version to match (infact, its actually a little newer than the original now!).

I have exported the databases shown when i ran **Get-SPContentDatabase** and I have them in .bak format.

I tried importing at the other end, starting with WSS_Content, however there is already a WSS_Content database in SQL. how would one go about restoring these databases?

Also, once I have the databases in the new servers SQL, is that the time when I need to start using STSADM to remove the old permissions or are there other steps involved?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reason why you have the same content DB name on both farm is, You are using the Default Name for the Content DB when provision a new web application.

Now you have two options.

1. On the destination Farm, detach the WSS-Content db from the web application then wither rename it or delete it( if you are not using it). After that restore the Content db then attach it to the web app.
2. Restore the content DB with different Name( this will not change the Content or functionality of DB). After restoring to different name then attach it to the Web Application.